# Solr not escapes white spaces for searching

Tags: solr

I use Solr server with version 6.4.1.

I need to search field which could contain spec symbols like `-_.`. But at the same time, I need an opportunity to find the entity without those symbols.

For example, the value is `G2-5SG`. I should find it by next queries: `G2 5SG`, `G2-5SG`, `G25SG`.

I have following configuration for the type:

```
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\w+)([-_.\s])" replacement="$1"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="16"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\w+)([-_.\s])" replacement="$1"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

Search with spec symbols works fine. But when I try to search word without symbols server returns an empty set.

Values in analyzer are marked as satisfying, for index `G2 5SG` and for query `G25SG`.

Answer (score 1):

one thing that would work would be:

- use a copyfield to have two fields fed with the same text, but analyzed differently
- one field you keep with those symbols you need, maybe just lowercase, and use KeywordTokenizerFactory
- the second field is similar, but remove all such chars, leave just alphanumeric values
- now you use edismax parser to search in both fields. Besides, you can give more weight to the first field, that is more 'real' than the second. So you will have improved relevancy

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
```

This tokenizer splits the text field into tokens, treating whitespace and punctuation as delimiters.

instead of

```
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
```

This tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token.

You may try something like below.

```
<fieldtype name="subword" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> 
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
           <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

For more details please refer the tokenizer page [Tokenizers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers)

Comment: I have ClassNotFoundException: solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory when try to load the config

Comment: @sanitar4eg : Try with solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Comment: yep, tried with this class, but have the same result. And it's strange because by analyzer I can't find `G2 5SG` for query `G2 5SG` but the row is finded.

Comment: I think it is not what I want. I don't see opportunity in this solution for finding values without white spaces

Comment: @sanitar4eg : Did you added it as new fieldType in your schema.xml and Did you apply the same for your field. After the same changes you need to restart the server and re-index the data. You can verify the same in solr admin page by checking how the data is been indexed and how it is been queried.

Comment: yes, I did and saw updates in the analyzer. I updated me old type. but split words into many tokens not really what I want.

Comment: @sanitar4eg : you can control the same by adding the attribute to the wordDelimiterFilterFactory...Attributes are generateWordParts="1",
generateNumberParts="1" , catenateWords="0" ,         catenateNumbers="0" , catenateAll="0", preserveOriginal="1". Please read more about it on the wiki page shared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151487/discussion-between-sanitar4eg-and-abhijit-bashetti).